# Can't make it work, new to coding, would love some help. timer based filling in unity

Tags: c#

thanks for taking a look. I'm having some fun, with unity, and I would like a timerbased square to fill up, with the passing of time. Starting off as nonexistent and then growing to be completely filled.

```
//
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;


public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    Image fillImg;
    float time;
    float howlong = 11;
    float fillAmount = 1;
    int deduction;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        fillImg = this.GetComponent<Image>();
        time = 0;
        float deduction = Time.timeScale/howlong;
        Debug.Log("deduction = " + deduction);
        Debug.Log(Time.timeScale);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(time < 1){
            time += Time.deltaTime*deduction;
            Debug.Log(time);
            fillImg.fillAmount = time; // ?


        }

    }

}
```

The Debug.Log for time, always returns 0, i think its because of rounding but I'm not entirely sure. I tried debug.log on Time.deltaTime to see if there was any problems there, but it didn't seem to appear so.
removing the *deduction part of time += Time.deltaTime*deduction, made the square fill up, but I'm looking to be able to define how long its supposed to take, i'd really love to learn more, and so any alternate solutions to the problem in its entirety would be very much appreciated! For reference sake, the float howlong is how long its gonna have to take to fill it up!

Comment: Please provide appropriate title for your question

Answer (score 0):

In `Timer` class there is member variable `deduction`.

```
    int deduction;
```

but in `Start` function, you declare local variable with same name `deduction`

```
        float deduction = Time.timeScale/howlong;
```

so you only modifies local variable `deduction`, not member of class. So member `deduction` is always 0 in

```
            time += Time.deltaTime*deduction;
```

thus `time` resulting in 0.

Comment: Removing the 'int deduction;' results in Error CS0103 "The name deduction does not exist in the current context. While changing the first one to be the same as in the start function results in Error CS0236 " a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property Timer.howlong

Comment: Try changing ```int deduction;``` to ```float deduction = 0;``` and ```float deduction = Time.timeScale/howlong;``` to ```deduction = Time.timeScale/howlong;```.